# Get bean from ApplicationContext by qualifier

Tags: spring

Given this code:

```
public interface Service {}

@Component
@Qualifier("NotWanted")
public class NotWantedService implements Service {}

@Component
@Qualifier("Wanted")
public class WantedService implements Service {}

AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ctx.register(NotWantedService.class);
ctx.register(WantedService.class);
ctx.refresh()
```

How do I now do:

```
ctx.getBean(Service.class)
```

in a way that will only get the one with `@Qualifier("Wanted")` and not the one with `@Qualifier("NotWanted")`? I'm specifically asking if it's possible to do it using `getBean`, not injecting to a class, then using that one as a kind of proxy.

Comment: Why not getting bean by name since you're using name constant, i.e. `ctx.getBean("Wanted")`?

Comment: @aux Say you have 50 places where you do `ctx.getBean("service1")` and you now want to change it to `ctx.getBean("service2")`. That's 50 changes. Changing the qualifier is change to 2 bean definitions (`service1` and `service2`) only. There are other cases, too - say I want to get multiple `Service` instances that are `Wanted`. They cannot all have the same bean name.

Comment: OK, i see. Then what about introducing your own "registry" bean that holds references to your beans and used for lookup by different parameters, like `Repositories` in spring-data-rest? Or a wrapper bean?

Comment: @aux See last sentence in the question. I wanted to know if I wanted to do away with the indirection. In other words, I have a working solution, trying to see if there's a better one (read: less code).

Answer (score 34):

You can use

```
BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(ctx.getBeanFactory(), Service.class, "Wanted")
```

It's important to use `ctx.getBeanFactory()`, not `ctx` itself, because the 'qualifiedBeanOfType' method can resolve qualifiers only for ConfigurableListenableBeanFactory.

Comment: How can I get `ctx.getBeanFactory()` when I use `application.run()` to get the `ctx`?

Comment: @UnixAgain did you try ``new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()`` instance of ``ctx``?

Comment: @UnixAgain Use applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()

Comment: @AbhishekChatterjee thanks . I finally find the reason out. My class of bean is implemented as a singleton, so the instance is the same one. More details of my solution is posted under this question.

Comment: @TuGordoBello  thanks . I finally find the reason out. My class of bean is implemented as a singleton, so the instance is the same one. More details of my solution is posted under this question.

Answer (score 11):

It's not the `@Qualifier` annotation's purpose to use it when getting beans via ApplicationContext. But since you need such or similar functionality for some reasons, I suggest a workaround.

Create `@Wanted` and `@NotWanted` annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.FIELD,
        ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Wanted {
}
```

and

```
@Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.FIELD,
            ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NotWanted {
}
```

Annotate your bean classes with these new annotations:

```
@Component
@NotWanted
public class NotWantedService implements Service {}
```

and

```
@Component
@Wanted
public class WantedService implements Service {}
```

Then you should add 2 methods somewhere where you have access to the `ApplicationContext` :

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private <T> Collection<T>  getBeansByTypeAndAnnotation(Class<T> clazz, Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType){
    Map<String, T> typedBeans = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(clazz);
    Map<String, Object> annotatedBeans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(annotationType);
    typedBeans.keySet().retainAll(annotatedBeans.keySet());
    return typedBeans.values();
}

private <T> Optional<T> getBeanByTypeAndAnnotation(Class<T> clazz, Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType) {
    Collection<T> beans = getBeansByTypeAndAnnotation(clazz, annotationType);
    return beans.stream().findFirst();
}
```

And now you can use them to get beans or one bean by annotation and type like this:

```
Collection<Service> services = getBeansByTypeAndAnnotation(Service.class, Wanted.class);
```

or

```
Service service = getBeanByTypeAndAnnotation(Service.class, Wanted.class);
```

Possibly it's not the best way to deal with the problem. But since we are unable to get beans from `ApplicationContext` by qualifier and type 'out of box', that's one of the ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks @Rozart - I tried that already. Unfortunately, that does not take `@Qualifier` into consideration. It takes the name of the bean, specified with `@Bean(name="abc")`, which is not the same.

Comment: That's the same as the `@Bean(name="abc")` though, it doesn't have the same semantics. You cannot have two beans named the same, but you can have more than one qualified the same. That is, I want 10 different services qualified with "Wanted", but not at all called "Wanted".

Comment: I've updated the answer. Maybe that will help you. :)

Comment: Thanks Rozart. Can you clarify this: "It's not the @Qualifier annotation's purpose to use it when getting beans via ApplicationContext."? It might not be supported at the moment, but why would that be logically inconsistent?

Comment: That's exacly what I meant by 'It's not the @Qualifier's purpose' - it's not supported currently. Logically IMO it is consistent, but not yet supported.
I hope my answer helped you. ;)

Comment: Thanks Rozart - it did not answer the question, though it has some useful information that might come in handy.

Comment: @levantpied You should file a feature request with Spring.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I have two qualified bean of one class, e.g

```java
@Configuration
public class AConfig {
    @Bean(name = "a")
    public Hello hello1() {
        return new Hello();
    }

    @Bean(name = "b")
    public Hello hello2() {
        return new Hello();
    }
}
```

Then I can get a specific bean by

```java
ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(AutoConfiguration.class); 
var aHello = context.getBean("a", Hello.class); 
var bHello = context.getBean("b", Hello.class);
```

This is the simplest way of doing this. Or you can do the same thing as below:

```java
var aHello = context.getBeansOfType(Hello.class).getBean("a");
var bHello = context.getBeansOfType(Hello.class).getBean("b");
```

Or you can also do as @Dmitry Ovchinnikov says:

```java
BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(ctx.getBeanFactory(), Service.class, "Wanted")
```

In this case, `ctx.getBeanFactory()` can be replaced by `context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()`.

Comment: The `context.get()` method gives me a `BeanDefinitionOverrideException`.

Comment: @bart-kosmala Sorry it's `context.getBean()`

Comment: @UnixAgain, you provide bean names, not bean qualifier. You specify qualifiers using the org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier annotation.

Comment: Your solutions seem interesting, although I can't find out what AutoConfiguration.class is supposed to be (tried a few dependencies although I'm unable to import that class)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get bean from context not injecting, better way to define bean name in @Component annotation and get it by name from context. In most cases @Qualifier is used for injections.

Answer (score 2):

The closest canonical way to do this in Spring is with the utility class [BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.html#qualifiedBeanOfType-org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) ... but this sadly only works with `@Qualifier` annotation value argument directly (hence why the argument is a string).

What [@Rozart is recommending](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34798524/318174) is the best approach and really something like that should be in `BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils`. I only included the above answer in the case someone lands here and does want to use `@Qualifier` directly (and all the bean aliasing that comes along with it).

I recommend filing a feature request in Spring (I would but I think they might be tired of me bugging them :-) ).