# How to use `javax.inject.Qualifier` to get bean in spring application context?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, inject, jsr330

JSR-330 provide `@Qualifier` to qualifies beans. For example, define the following qualifier annotation.

```
@Qualifier
@interface Category{
  String value();
}
```

and use it like this

```
@Bean
@Category("simple")
SomeThing get(){
  return ...
}

@Inject
@Category("simple")
SomeThing sth;
```

It does work.

But how can I get the bean from `ApplicationContext`?

```
ApplicationContext context
context... // how to get the @Category("simple") bean
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/44029485/814304

Comment: @iMysak No, it is `spring.Qualifier`, not `javax.inject.Qualifier`.