# Dependency injection according to conditions

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/mypath")
public class MyController {
   @Autowired
   MyServiceInterface service;

   @PostMapping("/{source}")
   void myControllerFunc(@PathVariable String source, @RequestBody MyObject obj) {
       ...
       Object myServiceObj = service.myServiceFunc(param);
       ...
   }
}
```

My Service Interface:

```
public interface MyServiceInterface {

   Object myServiceFunc(String param);

}
```

My Service Implemantations:

```
@Service    
public class MyServiceOne {

   Object myServiceFunc(String param) {
       ...
   }

}

@Service
public class MyServiceTwo {

   void myServiceFunc(String param) {
       ...
   }

}
```

My spring-boot version : 1.5.7

I want to inject the service according to my path variable ("source") . If source = one, inject MyServiceOne or if source = two, inject MyServiceTwo.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need both of these to be available and each method invocation on the controller can choose a different one. So wire up both implementations, with a qualifier to distinguish them. Use the path variable in the controller method and let it decide programmatically which service to call.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible and reasonable.

A `@RestController`s is by nature a singleton. It gets configured at startup and remains the same for every request.

The expression `/{source}` is being evaluated during a request at runtime, when the controller has already been set up.

The options to consider:

1. Inject both services and, in the method, decide which one to pick.
2. Create two separate controllers for each service.
3. <strike>Utilise the application context and extract beans from there.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Get bean from ApplicationContext by qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798459/get-bean-from-applicationcontext-by-qualifier), you could add qualifiers to each service implementations and have something like this in the `myControllerFunc`:

```
BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(ctx.getBeanFactory(), MyServiceInterface.class, source)
```