# Lookup prototype bean by custom annotation attribute

Tags: java, spring, prototype, lookup

I have an custom qualifier annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface MyQualifier {
    MyQualiferEnum value();
}
```

And some beans

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@MyQualifier(MyQualifierEnum.BLACK)
public class BlackBean {

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@MyQualifier(MyQualifierEnum.WHITE)
public class WhiteBean {
```

I try @Lookup but it rely on bean name or class and I can't pass annotation and it attributes to lookup-method

Then I try

```
context.getgetBeansWithAnnotation(MyQualifier.class)
```

but it leads to all @MyQualifier beans instantiated that worse for me.

I can't introduce @MyQualifierBlack, @MyQualiferWhite etc separate annotations, I exactly need enum so how I can inject that prototype beans depends on MyQualifierEnum value, for example MyQualifierEnum.BLACK, at runtime without unnecessary initialization of other @MyQualifier annotated beans?

Comment: So you want to look up the bean via context or some other programatical means instead of @Inject/@Autowiring them into your classes? Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798459/get-bean-from-applicationcontext-by-qualifier

Comment: @sfiss no matter. I can use context and annotation-way both. I research your reference early and can't find solution for my queistion

Comment: Is your code working with a different scope? Could you post the code at the injection site?

Answer (score 0):

The following setup uses only [JSR-330](https://javax-inject.github.io/javax-inject/) annotations. I did not test it yet for spring, but it works using e.g. [hk2](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/) as the implementation:

```
@MyQualifier(MyQualifierEnum.BLACK)
// Framework-specific annotations, e.g. @Component/@Service and @Scope
public class BlackService implements QualifiableService { }

@MyQualifier(MyQualifierEnum.WHITE)
// Framework-specific annotations, e.g. @Component/@Service and @Scope
public class WhiteService implements QualifiableService { }

@Qualifier
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyQualifier {

    public static enum MyQualifierEnum {
        WHITE, BLACK;
    }

    MyQualifier.MyQualifierEnum value();
}

// Framework-specific annotations
public interface QualifiableService { }

// Framework-specific annotations, e.g. @Component/@Service and @Scope
public class TestComponent {

    @MyQualifier(MyQualifierEnum.BLACK)
    @Inject
    private QualifiableService black;

    @MyQualifier(MyQualifierEnum.WHITE)
    @Inject
    private QualifiableService white;

    @MyQualifier(MyQualifierEnum.WHITE)
    @Inject
    private Provider<QualifiableService> whiteProvider;

    @MyQualifier(MyQualifierEnum.BLACK)
    @Inject
    private Provider<QualifiableService> blackProvider;

    void test() {
        final QualifiableService white = whiteProvider.get();
        final QualifiableService black = blackProvider.get();
    }
}
```

Make sure you register both implementations (e.g. package scanning in your case) and inject the correct one via qualifier. The [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) implementation of annotations should suffice to ensure the correct component is injected.

In the case you use a narrower scope (e.g. prototype scope), using a (qualified) `Provider` seems the easiest solution. Alternatively, you could try to inject a proxy (e.g. using springs proxy mechanism).